# How to remove hourly update from =importdata script?

Tags: google-sheets

Below is a script I have to import data from a csv link. However, I notice it updates every hour, unless I have a trigger added to it. Is there a way to remove the hourly update so that way, the only way for it to update is when I attach the script to an image I will use as a button?

```
function backlog() 
{
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Backend Data!A2').setValue('=importdata("samplecsvlink")')
}
```

Comment: I added a trigger for spreadsheet—on change. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, you're setting up the cell on A2 with =importdata("samplecsvlink"). Thus, the sheet will still aggregate [live data](https://www.geckoboard.com/blog/4-ways-to-automagically-get-your-data-into-spreadsheets/) from the CSV link using the `=importdata()` function, even if you use a trigger.

**Recommendation**

You may refer to this sample code below (I've used a publicly available CSV link online for this sample) to only get the CSV data every time you run a script, place them into a variable array, then set the array data on the `Backend Data` sheet starting on cell `A2`up to whatever the size of the CSV data:

```
function importCSV() { //Imports the CSV data from the URL into the variable array 'csvData' and returns that variable array
  var csvUrl = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  return csvData;
}

function backlog(){ //Sets the imported CSV data to the 'Backend Data' sheet starts on A2 and beyond
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Backend Data').clear().getRange(2, 1, importCSV().length, importCSV()[0].length).setValues(importCSV()); //Added a .clear() method to clean any old data that could mess your 'Backend Data' sheet before posting the new updated ones, especially on scenarios like if the updated CSV data decreases in number (row count)
}
```

**The test 'Backend Data' sheet I've used:**

[image]

**Result** after clicking "RUN" image with `backlog` function:

[image]